# How to format llvm output produced by GHC

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc

I explore GHC features and how they affect machine code.

```
ghc -ddump-simpl -ddump-llvm Main.hs
```

Command above generates llvm file, snippet is below.
I wasn't able to find what it is the format and any tool making output more readable with indentations and line breaks. Like I did here manually. The content is smashed into a single line. I guess must be some flag to improve human readability.

```
internal global %Main_zdtcSubRegUnTup3_closure_struct<{
  i64 ptrtoint (i8* @ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_TyCon_con_info to i64), 
  i64 add (i64 ptrtoint (%Main_zdtrModule_closure_struct* @Main_zdtrModule_closure$def to i64),i64 1), 
  i64 add (i64 ptrtoint (%r24c_closure_struct* @r24c_closure$def to i64),i64 1), 
  i64 ptrtoint (i8* @ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_krepzdzt_closure to i64), 
  i64 3059269072134316734, 
  i64 -1793863935995381901, 
  i64 0, 
  i64 0
}>
```

Comment: What you're looking at is LLVM IR, a low-level language in the tradition of assembly languages. This class of language has no lexical blocks and is almost universally written with one statement per line. IR, like assembly in general, is very hard to read if you want a high-level language but IR is fairly readable if you really want the low-level details of what's going on.

Comment: What you show here is essentially the same as what I see on my machine from `-ddump-llvm` in terms of line breaks and indentation. Can you give a minimal reproducible example that shows what you don't like? Be sure to include which version of GHC you're using.